# Angular Universal with Angular Service Worker

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I'm working on a project that uses SSR and SW same time.

SSR is working perfectly on first render, and when crawler reads page.

On the other hand Service Worker is working nicely too.

But problem occurs after Service Worker caches **index.html** file.

Here are steps that reproduces problem:

1. When you open page first, you see that SSR rendered html and you get result instantly
2. Then Service Worker caches everything
3. When you refresh or change page, you don't see SSR rendered html, because index.html was cached by Service Worker
4. If you remove index.html from caching Service Worker crashes

I'm using Angular 7.0

This is **ngsw-config.json** that I'm using:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/favicon.ico", "/index.html", "/*.css", "/*.js"]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/assets/**"]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api",
      "urls": ["https://example.com/**"],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 30,
        "maxAge": "1d",
        "timeout": "30s",
        "strategy": "freshness"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How did u solve the PWA in Angular Universal? I am facing the problem. when i register ServiceWorkerModule in AppBrowserModule my PWA works but SSR doesn't. Can you tell me how did you solve that?

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed did you find the solution to your problem? Because I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @amansoni211 yea.. actually there is no problem. Since Service worker is already running on the browser so if you view "view-source" it will return the local cache index.html file instead of SSR. Basically your SSR works but u can't view it in browser bcz of PWA cache. Use "Post man" or curl command or any REST client to get the compiled SSR file.

Comment: Did you try https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch show? Does your crawled website has any content?